# Disable selection of rows in a datagridview

Tags: .net, winforms, datagridview, user-interface

I want to disable the selection of certain rows in a datagridview.

It must be possible to remove the select property for one or more datagridview rows in a datagridview shown in a winform. The goal is that the user can't select certain rows. (depending on a condition)

Thankx,

Comment: For those who found this question to know how to disable rows selection at all:
set `SelectionMode` property to `CellSelect`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If SelectionMode is FullRowSelect, then you'll need to override SetSelectedRowCore for that DataGridView, and not call the base SetSelectedRowCore for rows you don't want selected.

If SelectionMode is not FullRowSelect, you'll want to additionally override SetSelectedCellCore (and not call the base SetSelectedCellCore for rows you don't want selected), as SetSelectedRowCore will only kick in if you click the row header and not an individual cell.

Here's an example:

```
public class MyDataGridView : DataGridView
{
    protected override void SetSelectedRowCore(int rowIndex, bool selected)
    {
        if (selected && WantRowSelection(rowIndex))
        {
            base.SetSelectedRowCore(rowIndex, selected);
        }
     }

     protected virtual void SetSelectedCellCore(int columnIndex, int rowIndex, bool selected)
     {
         if (selected && WantRowSelection(rowIndex))
         {
            base.SetSelectedRowCore(rowIndex, selected);
          }
     }

     bool WantRowSelection(int rowIndex)
     {
        //return true if you want the row to be selectable, false otherwise
     }
}
```

If you're using WinForms, crack open your designer.cs for the relevant form, and change the declaration of your DataGridView instance to use this new class instead of DataGridView, and also replace the this.blahblahblah = new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView() to point to the new class.

Comment: A Solution that works... But for this I think we need to create a Class which extends datagridview control... Am I Right...
Don't we have a solution that works on current datagridview class

Comment: I would like to ask if there is a facility to only highlight certain column even if the row is set as selected.

Comment: @szevvy, can you explain further?  I'm in need of this answer right now, as well.

Comment: @Sev09 - No problem, added code sample + description of how to use it.

Comment: I think this will still unselect whatever is currently selected. Is there a way to both prohibit selection of certain cells and (in that case) keep current selection?

Comment: Cool. To also support deselection, just use `if (WantRowSelection(rowIndex))`

Answer (score -1):

```
Private Sub dgvSomeDataGridView_SelectionChanged(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles dgvSomeDataGridView.SelectionChanged
        dgvSomeDataGridView.ClearSelection()
End Sub
```